# ArcGIS 10.5 FME Data Interoperability ArcGIS Online reader not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, fme-form, data-interoperability, arcgis-10.5

Just upgraded from ArcGIS 10.3.1 to 10.5 and now Data Interop will not read any AGO data. This goes for tools made in 10.3.1 and new tools started from scratch in 10.5. Below is the log. The problem is at `Python Exception <NameError>: global name 'resp' is not defined`

The same error comes up whether I am trying to run an old tool with the reader already on the workbench or when I try to add the reader in a new tool.

This is on windows 7 64 bit. I did not uninstall any old ArcGIS software.

```
Creating reader for format: Esri ArcGIS Online (AGOL) Feature Service
Trying to find a PYTHON plugin for reader named `ARCGISONLINEFEATURES'
Using FME's provided Python interpreter from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\fmepython27\python27.dll'
Python version 2.7 loaded successfully
Loaded Python module `arcgisonlinefeatures' from file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\plugins/python27\arcgisonlinefeatures\__init__.pyc'
Creating reader for format: Esri ArcGIS Online (AGOL) Feature Service
Trying to find a PYTHON plugin for reader named `ARCGISONLINEFEATURES'
Loaded Python module `arcgisonlinefeatures' from file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\plugins/python27\arcgisonlinefeatures\__init__.pyc'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Logging into 'https://www.arcgis.com/' as user 'John.lastName'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Requesting portal information
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in the root folder for user 'John.lastName'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in the subfolder 'Survey-testWeedsprayNoguid' for user 'John.lastName'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in the subfolder 'Weed Spray' for user 'John.lastName'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Searching for all groups in the organization accessible to user 'lastName'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in group 'Habitat'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in group 'Region 3'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in group 'GFP Basedata'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in group 'Wildlife Surveys'
ArcGIS Online Feature Service Reader: Getting list of items in group 'Fisheries'
Python Exception <NameError>: global name 'resp' is not defined
A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
Merged 0 schema features read from 1 datasets into 0 resulting feature types
UniversalReader -- readSchema resulted in 0 schema features being returned
Reader Parameter(0) = ><Unused><
Reader Parameter(1) = >RETRIEVE_ALL_FS_NAMES<
Reader Parameter(2) = >Yes<
Reader Parameter(3) = >USER<
Reader Parameter(4) = >John.lastName<
Reader Parameter(5) = >PASSWORD<
Reader Parameter(6) = >********<
Reader Parameter(7) = >_MERGE_SCHEMAS<
Reader Parameter(8) = >YES<
Reader Directive(0) = >RUNTIME_MACROS<
Reader Directive(1) = >RETRIEVE_ALL_FS_NAMES,Yes,USER,John.lastName,PASSWORD,********,_MERGE_SCHEMAS,YES<
Configuration object contents:
FME Temporary Folder: C:\Users\GFSF12~1\AppData\Local\Temp
mapping file Line 0: `APPLICATION' `FME_WORKBENCH'
mapping file Line 1: `AUTOREG' `YES'
mapping file Line 2: `LOG_MAX_FEATURES' `-1'
mapping file Line 3: `LOG_APPEND' `NO'
mapping file Line 4: `FME_HOME' `C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\'
mapping file Line 5: `FME_SESSION_USED' `TRUE'
mapping file Line 6: `R_1_METAFILE' `ARCGISONLINEFEATURES'
mapping file Line 7: `R_1_DATASET' `<Unused>'
mapping file Line 8: `R_1_RETRIEVE_ALL_FS_NAMES' `Yes'
mapping file Line 9: `R_1_USER' `John.lastName'
mapping file Line 10: `R_1__MERGE_SCHEMAS' `YES'
mapping file Line 11: `R_1_RETRIEVE_ALL_FS_NAMES' `Yes'
mapping file Line 12: `R_1_USER' `John.lastName'
mapping file Line 13: `R_1__MERGE_SCHEMAS' `YES'
mapping file Line 14: `R_1_MERGE_SCHEMAS' `YES'
mapping file Line 15: `R_1_FEATURESERVICE' `'
mapping file Line 16: `SCHEMA_TIME' `YES'
mapping file Keyword: `R_1_MERGE_SCHEMAS'                      occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `LOG_MAX_FEATURES'                       occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `AUTOREG'                                occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `SCHEMA_TIME'                            occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `R_1_FEATURESERVICE'                     occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `LOG_APPEND'                             occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `R_1_PASSWORD'                           occurs 2 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `FME_SESSION_USED'                       occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `R_1_METAFILE'                           occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `R_1_DATASET'                            occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `R_1_RETRIEVE_ALL_FS_NAMES'              occurs 2 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `R_1_USER'                               occurs 2 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `FME_HOME'                               occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `APPLICATION'                            occurs 1 time(s)
mapping file Keyword: `R_1__MERGE_SCHEMAS'                     occurs 2 time(s)
UniversalReader -- readSchema resulted in 0 schema features being returned
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm told this is a known issue and that, happily, a patched file has been made available and is easy to install.

For ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 Data Interoperability, the fix is simply to copy the patched file (`arcgisonlineCommon.pyc`) to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\python\python27\arcgisonline\`

Obviously that will require Administrative permissions to do, but then the AGOL format should work fine.

I've got a copy of the file and made it available on [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1pmf3qcn081qdo/arcgisonlineCommon.pyc?dl=0).

Esri are aware of the issue and have a copy of the file so it should be in future updates/installers. But I don't know if their support team has a copy, so if the Dropbox link doesn't work, contact [Safe Software](http://safe.com/support) for the file.