# Quick Import FME Reader Gallery Not Populated with FDS (ArcGIS 10.5 Adv Licence)

Tags: geojson, fme-form

I wanted to import GeoJSON files, but after installing the Background GP and Data Interop packages, I find that the FME Gallery contains only GML and WFS formats. This is with both ArcGIS 10.4 and ArcGIS 10.5 on advanced licence.

I tried this solution : 
[ArcGIS 10.5 FME Data Interoperability ArcGIS Online reader not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238249/arcgis-10-5-fme-data-interoperability-arcgis-online-reader-not-working)

..but it did not make any difference.

I can use QGIS to get the files for now but is there a libary online where I can import FDS files?

Comment: was FME installed before or after ArcGIS 10.5?

Comment: It was installed after

Answer (score 0):

Using ArcGIS 10.6 (32 bit)

and FME 2018.1 (FME(R) 2018.1.0.3 (20180926 - Build 18552 - WIN64)

using the Quick Translator shows the GeoJSON is available and licensed.

tip type: json rather than geojson

[image]